# "choose when" with variables XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to set the color of a table row according to the float value ..

```
....
<xsl:variable name="percent">
<xsl:value-of select="float(PercentageValue)" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="color">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$PercentageValue &ge; 75.0">green</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$PercentageValue &lt; 75.0 and $PercentageValue &ge; 50.0">orange</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>red</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<tr bgcolor="$color">
....
```

what i want is ..

```
if(percent>=75)
tableRowColor=green;
else if(percent>=50.0 && percent <75.0)
tableRowColor=orange;
else
tableRowColor=red;
```

Im relatively new to XSLT syntax .. what is the problem present above?
Help appreciated!

Edit 1: Sorry a typo while copy pasting for the variable being $PercentageValue
Here is what ive done now ..

```
....
<xsl:variable name="PercentageValue">
        <xsl:value-of select="number(percent)" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="color">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$PercentageValue &gt;= 75.0">green</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$PercentageValue &lt; 75.0 and $PercentageValue &gt;= 50.0">orange</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>red</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
<tr bgcolor="$color">
.....
```

Now i do get the colors but all are black ..why so?

Here is how im displaying
[image: Without using any bgcolor attribute for tr]
Percentage values are at the end .. which is selected in a td for that tr so it does get displayed .. 
actually the whole xml and xsl are dynamically generated via java, therefore there is alot of precision(double) over there . .does that cause a problem?

Comment: `&ge;` is not a standard XML entity. Use `&gt;=` (Expressions in XSLT are basically XPath plus some additional functions, but the `<`, `>`, and `&` characters have to be escaped since XSLT is an XML language.)

Comment: @keshlam Only `<` and `&` MUST be escaped; `>` can be used as is unless preceded by `]]`: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#dt-chardata

Comment: Please post the code (XML input, your XSLT) necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: its not feasible to post the whole xml and xslt .. as xml is around 1.5k LOC and xslt another 70 .. i'll post the structure if you want .. both xml and xsl are generated by some operations on DB data by my java prgm

Comment: @michael.hor257k mind telling me when to use `select="{$var}"` and when to use `select="$var"`

Comment: You only need to post samples large enough to reproduce the issue. In your place, I too would be working on a sample first.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: True. I used to be a stickler about that point myself. I've found that it's simpler not to argue with people about it; this is the first time I've had anyone other than myself complain about overprotecting the beginners. :-P

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of issues:

- Your variable is assigned as `percent` but you reference `$PercentageValue`
- Convert a number using the `number()` function
- And use `gt;=` and `lt;` for comparisons

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <xsl:variable name="PercentageValue">
        <xsl:value-of select="number(PercentageValue)" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="color">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$PercentageValue &gt;= 75.0">green</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$PercentageValue &lt; 75.0 and $PercentageValue &gt;= 50.0">orange</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>red</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <TheColorIs>
        <xsl:value-of select="$color"/>
    </TheColorIs>
</xsl:template>
```

On this Xml:

```
<xml>
    <PercentageValue>77</PercentageValue>
</xml>
```

As an aside, instead of creating lots of variables and imperatively 'switching' using `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose / xsl:when`, remember that you can also use template filtering to apply matching:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/xml/PercentageValue[number() &gt;= 75]">
        <color>green</color>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/xml/PercentageValue[number() &lt; 75.0 and number() &gt;= 50.0]">
        <color>orange</color>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Intriguing - what does view source on the html show? (I can't believe it would be `<tr bgcolor="black">`). My guess is the `percent` xpath doesn't match, e.g. missing namespace or incorrect path / context type issue. Also note that `tr bgcolor` is now marked [obsolete in Html 5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/tr.html)

Comment: edited .. and then how do i go about setting the color to tr? .. wait i'll use classes

Comment: im thinking its because of '%' .. sorry for that .. remove those but still all rows are black

Comment: `tr class="red/green/orange"` and then add css classes accordingly.

Comment: Yes, the % is causing problems with `number()`

Comment: ive removed the '%' from xml generation but still i get all table rows as black .. and does double precision cause a problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45336/discussion-between-cooperhawk-and-stuartlc)

Comment: @cooperHawk - In your example you used `bgcolor="$color"`. It should be `bgcolor="{$color}"`. Verify you're using an AVT ([attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)).